# How to make inverse switch with bc547?

Tags: transistors, batteries, switches

I want to make a circuit where the power to mcu switches from mains transformer to dc battery when when mains power is not available.

The basic concept is to use a transistor to stay open circuit to keep the battery from supplying the mcu while the mains transformer is active.

Once mains power goes out it should make the transistor conductive and close the circuit with battery.

In a nutshell when mains power is on transistor is off and vice versa

A complimentary congiguration with pnp would have been ideal but I'm limited to using bc548 atm

Please guide me to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3aNp8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) The diode version. (b) The BC548 version, if that's all you've got.*

Either of these solutions should work if if \$ DC_{MAINS+} > V_{BAT} \$.

Comment: what the hell! why didn't (a) cross my mind -_- yes DC mains + is almost double of VBat so (a) should work fine I suppose, what is the technical term for design (a) ?

Comment: No proper name as far as I know. It's similar to a diode OR gate for simple digital logic. "Dual power input with anti-backfeed protection"?